# How can create N items of a specific element in c#?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am looking for a way to generate N pieces of question marks joined with comma.

```
string element="?";
string sep=",";
int n=4;
// code to run and create ?,?,?,?
```

- EDIT 1

I am looking in a simple way. Probably using 1-2 line of code. In c++ there are array fill() and joins.

- EDIT 2

I need this for **Compact Framework**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static class Extensions
{
     public static string Times(this string s, int count)
     {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(count * s.Length);
          for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
          {
              sb.Append(s);
          }
          return sb.ToString();
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("?,".Times(5).Trim(','));
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the new Enumerable.Repeat method in conjunction with String.Join:

```
String.Join(sep, Enumerable.Repeat(element, n).ToArray());
```

Comment: what would be the long path for Enumerable eg : System.Collections. Generic.Enumerable ..... ? I can't find it. I am CompactFramework.

Comment: @Pentium10 - System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat - not sure if linq is in CF

Comment: It turns out it doesn't help me, as I am not on Compact Framework 3.5 Anyway thanks for the effort, I will use other one.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(element, n).DefaultIfEmpty("").Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + sep + s2);
```

Comment: what would be the long path for Enumerable eg : System.Collections. Generic.Enumerable ..... ? I can't find it. I am CompactFramework.

Comment: It's System.Linq.Enumerable in System.Core, but I don't know if it's in CF as well.

Comment: I think all these one liners are way too clever. Having one line do several things at once doesn't make it faster or more efficient. It just makes the code harder to understand. The simple string builder for loop is probably faster and it is certainly eaiser to understand.

Comment: According to the documentation, it's supported on CF 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx

Comment: It turns out it doesn't help me, as I am not on Compact Framework 3.5 Anyway thanks for the effort, I will use other one.

Answer (score 2):

```
static string BuildSeparatedString(string element, string sep, int count)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
  {
    sb.Append(element);

    if (i != count)
      sb.Append(sep);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

It's not fancy but neither is it a cryptic one liner. Anyone reading or maintaining the code should very quickly understand it.

By some quick testing this also runs nearly twice as fast as the two most popular one liners.

Answer (score 1):

In C# I would do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string element="?";
string sep=",";
int n=4;

for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
{
    sb.Append(element);
    sb.Append(sep);
}

if (sb.Length > 0)
{
    // remove the final separator
    sb.Length -= sep.Length;
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: What if `sep` isn't a single character?

Answer (score 0):

Not concise but it'll do the trick..

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(element);
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
   sb.Append(sep);
   sb.Append(element);
}
string output = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  sb.Append((i != n-1) ? "?," : "?");
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**One line**

```
String s = "".PadLeft(n-1, 'X').Replace("X", element+sep) + element;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string element = "?";
string sep = ",";
int n = 4;

string[] array = new string[n];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    array[i] = element;
}

string result = String.Join(sep, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string output = "?";
        int n = 4;
        while (n > 1)
        { output += "," + "?"; n--; }
```

Comment: Doesn't this increase exponentially? You end up with "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?" i.e. 16 ?'s not the required 4!

Comment: Thanks mate, have made the correction, It was not exponential. The string was repeated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner as well :)

```
 int n = 10;
 string element = "?";
 string sep = ",";

 string result = String.Join(sep, Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => element).ToArray());
```

Comment: what would be the long path for Enumerable eg : System.Collections. Generic.Enumerable ..... ? I can't find it. I am CompactFramework.

Comment: It turns out it doesn't help me, as I am not on Compact Framework 3.5 Anyway thanks for the effort, I will use other one.

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = String.Join(sep,Enumerable.Repeat(element, n).ToArray());
```

Comment: It turns out it doesn't help me, as I am not on Compact Framework 3.5 Anyway thanks for the effort, I will use other one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one-line expression to do what you want (with LINQ):

```
string.join(sep, (from x in Enumerable.Range(1, n) select element).ToArray())
```

Comment: It turns out it doesn't help me, as I am not on Compact Framework 3.5 Anyway thanks for the effort, I will use other one.